# Ruby - what's the difference between single and double quotes?

Tags: ruby

So I'm following this Ruby tutorial: [Learn Ruby the Hard Way.](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html)

In exercise 16 (linked above), you write a script that writes lines to a file. The relevant code is:

```
print "line 1: "; line1 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
print "line 2: "; line2 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
print "line 3: "; line3 = STDIN.gets.chomp()

puts "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
```

However, being the lazy bum that I am, I originally typed in the example using single quotes in the last six lines, instead of the double quotes the tutorial tells you to use.

This had an effect on the file. When I used single quotes, the file looked like this:

```
this is line 1\nthis is line 2\nthis is line 3
```

After switching those quotes to double-quotes, the file looked as expected:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
```

Can someone tell me exactly why that is? Do single-quoted strings just ignore escape characters like `\n` or `\t`?

Comment: *Really* lazy people don't type code, they copy/paste. :)

Comment: I am surprised that a tutorial that has you opening files and writing to them would not have taken the time somewhere along the way to explain how a string works.

Comment: I also felt tired of typing `"\n"` so frequently, so I use `$/`.

Comment: @Charles It is explained in [Chapter 10](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex10.html).

Comment: @steenslag Ah. Good! That makes me feel better. =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, single-quoted strings don't process ASCII escape codes and they don't do string interpolation.

```
name = 'Joe'
greeting = 'Hello, #{name}' # this won't produce "Hello, Joe"
```